# Failing to Connect To MongoDB from Company Network

Tags: mongodb, ssl, connection, failed-to-connect

What basic steps can I take to begin debugging a failing connection to a remote MongoDB?

When behind my company's network, I fail to connect to remotely hosted MongoDBs. When on my personal network at home, I can connect without issue.

I don't know how to go about debugging this issue.  The mongo shell --verbose option does not provide much information regarding where the hangup is occurring.  The only information provided is:

> 2018-02-22T12:30:23.393-0500 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to
>   My Address after 5000ms milliseconds, giving up.
>
> 2018-02-22T12:30:23.394-0500 D -        [thread1] User Assertion:
>   1:couldn't connect to server my_address, connection attempt failed
>   src\mongo\scripting\mozjs\mongo.cpp 712
>
> 2018-02-22T12:30:23.394-0500 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't
>   connect to server my_address, connection attempt failed :
>   connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13

Does anyone have any suggestions?

I'm using Windows 7 Professional, Service Pack 1. MongoDB shell version v3.6.2.

Comment: Are the MongoDB servers that you can't connect with when behind your company's network the only servers you can't connect with?

Comment: Yes.  I can connect to locally hosted servers and am also connected to the internet.  I think my main issue is that I'm not sure how to probe where in the "connect" process I'm having errors.  I don't have an in depth understanding of what a mongodb connection consists of, or how to step through the process of establishing one in order to identify my issues.